# How to define wildcard matching of url routes with angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to define **any** in url whit angular ui-router

in angular self router we can define a route like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:params*', {
    template: 'test',
  })
```

and when call this url

> /a/b/c

it's work

how can do same in angular ui-router

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For eager matching of URL parameters, use:

```
$stateProvider
.state('all', {
    url: "/*params",
    template: "test"
});

//OR

$stateProvider
.state('all', {
    url: "/{params:.*}",
    template: "test"
});
```

From the Docs:

> ### URL Regex Parameters
>
> Examples:
>
> - `'/files/{path:.*}'` - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
> - `'/files/*path'` - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.
>
> [— UI-Router Wiki URL-Routing regex parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters)